# Web Material Design: MDCTopAppBar, handle action click

Tags: javascript, material-design

I've got a definition, say, like this:

```
<header class="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--short">
  <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
    <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
      <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</a>
      <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Title</span>
    </section>
    <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
      <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item" aria-label="Bookmark this page" alt="Bookmark this page">bookmark</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

And then I create a MDCTopAppBar in javascript like so:

```
var myTAB = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar(myHTML);
```

...and wire up the menu click like so:

```
myTAB.listen("MDCTopAppBar:nav", function () { alert("Wevs"); });
```

My question is, how do I listen for a click on the action?  I can find nothing in the documentation and aren't familiar enough with the code base to easily find out from the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looking into it, there appears to be no event handling attached to the action icons by the material framework, but there is for the menu icon.  Weird.

You can just attach standard javascript event handlers to the  elements which are actions.

For example:

```
var myActionA = document.getElementById("myAction");
myActionA.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("Action clicked!"); }, false);
```